# woocommerce send email after order complet not work

Tags: gateway

I have creat a custom gatway for woocommerce (french bank cic)

My integration is ok ans work, but after check response bank my order is change in processing and i received no mail
see the code

```
if($order->status !== 'completed' && ($CMCIC_bruteVars['code-retour'] == "payetest" || $CMCIC_bruteVars['code-retour'] == "paiement")){
                            // Payment completed
                    $order->add_order_note( __('Paiement CM-CIC effectué:'.$CMCIC_bruteVars['numauto'], 'woocommerce') );
                    $order->payment_complete();


                    }elseif($order->status !== 'completed' && $CMCIC_bruteVars['code-retour'] == "Annulation"){
                        $order->update_status('cancelled', __('Paiement annulé', 'woocommerce'));
                    }
```

For information :
The payment is good 
check ipn return is good 
My order go to onhold at processing

Problem : no mail sent

If you have a solution :)

Comment: Hi, you don't have idea?

Comment: Hi, i don't have solved my problem. I have buy a plugin for this.. :(

Comment: Do other gateways (check and bank payment) also have the e-mail problem, or just your custom gateway?